# Optimizing LINQ query invoving Where Newbie C# / LINQ question

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

In the following simple, contrived example, I use in my Where clause a method (GetAutomaticCars).  This results in GetAutomaticCars being called four times.  I know one way to fix this.  Simply call GetAutomaticCars first and use the result in the query.  I've shown that it the commented lines below.  My question is:
Is this the only way to handle this?  It seems a little strange to me that the compiler can't optimize the call and realize it only needs to call GetAutomaticCars once.  I suppose the answer might be: "_cars collection could change (on another thread)".  If so, is there a way to indicate in C# that this is not the case?  Or must I do what I suggested and call GetAutomaticCars first?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CarTest test = new CarTest();
        test.PerformTest();
    }
}


public class CarTest
{
    List<Car> _cars = new List<Car>() { new Car(1, "Mustang", false), new Car(2, "Corvette", false), new Car(3, "Subaru", true), new Car(4, "Volvo", true) };
    public void PerformTest()
    {

        // this will just call GetAutomaticCars once
        //var automaticCars = GetAutomaticCars();
        //var optimalCars = _cars.Where(i => automaticCars.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(i.Id)).ToList();

        // this will call GetAutomaticCars 4 times
        var optimalCars = _cars.Where(i => !GetAutomaticCars().Select(p => p.Id).Contains(i.Id)).ToList(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Optimal Cars");
        foreach (var car in optimalCars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(car);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Car> GetAutomaticCars()
    {
        return _cars.Where(p => p.Automatic == true);
    }
}
public class Car
{
    public Car(int id, string name, bool automatic)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Automatic = automatic;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Automatic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A `Where` query is effectively a loop. If you had a loop, you wouldn't call the method within the loop, you'd call it once before you enter the loop. So yes, you should do the same here.

Comment: You do a Where on _cars in a Where on cars... are you sure you want to do this instead of only one Where? And do you need ToList?

Comment: You can use the `Join` between _cars and  GetAutomaticCars in that case, the `GetAutomaticCars` will be invoked once. Something like --- `_cars.Join(GetAutomaticCars()............)`

Comment: Thanks -user1672994, I'll play with that.  Oliviier, I simplified from proprietary code.  There is a ToList so I left it. And the Wheres make more sense in the longer actual code.

Comment: This should be enough: `var optimalCars = _cars.Where(car => car.Automatic != true);`

Comment: Your method returns a query, not query results, and the query isn't executed until the `ToList()` call. Have you measured the performance both ways and determined that there is a difference? Calling `GetAutomaticCars` and populating a separate list first may actually perform worse than just including the query it returns (but I'm not really sure).

Comment: See [Return a query from a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/return-a-query-from-a-method) for more info.

Comment: You could also do `foreach (var car in _cars.Except(GetAutomaticCars()))`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments everyone.  See StriplingWarrior's answer below and especially "var optimalCars = _cars.Except(GetAutomaticCars()); "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot that we could talk about here. e.g.:

- Various reasons why the compiler can't safely optimize away the call to a method.
- Ways that you could leverage IQueryables to come up with an unnecessarily complicated way to optimize away the call you're talking about.

But I think the most important point is that you've got logic (`p => p.Automatic == true`) that you want to have abstracted out into another method, and you'd like a simpler and more efficient way to apply this logic in a LINQ query than what you've come up with so far. Here's what I'd suggest:

```
    var optimalCars = _cars.Except(GetAutomaticCars());
```

You could also abstract the logic determining whether a car is automatic or not away from the concept of filtering the existing cars, and then use that logic more directly:

```
private IsCarAutomatic(Car c) => c.IsAutomatic;
private IsCarOptimal(Car c) => !IsCarAutomatic(c);

...
var optimalCars = _cars.Where(IsCarOptimal);
```

Comment: Thanks StriplingWarrior!  Your first example (_cars.Except(GetAutomaticCars()) is brilliant.  GetAutomaticCars is called only once as opposed to the original "Where" clause that I had.  I'd like to say I never heard of the "Except" command but in fact I just didn't think to use it in this circumstance.  This whole exercise has reinforced for me that it's very easy to write code that is not efficient.  The difference between one and four is nothing, but it my actual code there were thousands of "cars". Thank you!